# Play RTSP streaming in an Android application

Tags: android, streaming, live, rtsp, wowza

I am trying to develop an Android based application, which can play video from a live stream. This live stream is produced using [Wowza Media Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wowza_Streaming_Engine).

The URL is:

```
rtsp://tv.hindiworldtv.com:1935/live/getpun
```

I have tried following code in ecliplse:

```
package com.kalloh.wpa;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class a extends Activity {

    VideoView videoView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        //Create a VideoView widget in the layout file
        //use setContentView method to set content of the activity to the layout file which contains videoView
        this.setContentView(R.layout.videoplayer);

        videoView = (VideoView)this.findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        //add controls to a MediaPlayer like play, pause.
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        videoView.setMediaController(mc);

        //Set the path of Video or URI
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://tv.hindiworldtv.com:1935/live/getpnj"));
        //

        //Set the focus
        videoView.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

At first, it was not working.

Now it started working, but it stops after 20 to 30 seconds. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem using vlc, and found something here (which is not solution, but helpful information): http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=15229

Comment: Now the given url is working on Android 4 and above.. but still the problem is that audio is not continuous. It is something like 1 sec delay after 2 second play..

Comment: How you solve this issue?

Comment: Your code works on Nexus7 without any changes..

Comment: I tried on **Nexus10** with android version **4.4.4**, It gives `Can't play this video` exception.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I found the solution. Transmission should be within the preferred setting by Android. For more details, see *[Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)*.

Comment: What do you mean by "Transmission should be within preffered setting by Android"??

Comment: it mean "pre-buffered" maybe.

Comment: @SJSSoft What do u mean by this ? What's the solution ?

Comment: This problem occurs, if the stream you are dealing with, is not in one of the recommended format (Recommended by Google)

Comment: @SJSSoft: Can you give an example?

Comment: You found the solution but it's seem you can not give a example how to solve it?

Answer (score 13):

Using [VideoView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html) is a good solution, but we can also use the `native player` to play RTSP. This is an example:

```
if (movieurl.startsWith("rtsp://")) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(movieurl));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Bear in mind your media must be created with [**Android Supported Media Formats**](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) ([codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec)).

Comment: i don't get this, will this code open an installed app or is your app the video-displaying app?

Comment: If I stream within my app (with dvblast for example), when I open ThirdApp  (according to your solution), My current app goes to background and it doesn't broadcast anymore; so third opened app can't receive anything. How to handle this situation?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde: Maybe your broadcasting app should use a Service, so that it will keep running in the background?

Comment: which one is better? playing through "Native player" or through "video view"

Answer (score 9):

I also had the same problem in ICS 4.x. Also, you can check whether your stream [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) is working properly or not.

Also check your code with [this sample URL](http://www.wowza.com/html/mobile.html).

Comment: Thanks for posting a link to media that we know works! Very helpful

Comment: It doesn't work for mp3 stream, have you tried that. I'm also using Wowza server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Galaxy Note N7000 (ICS 4.0.3) and VLC 2.0.2 - the video dies after 60 seconds. But when I turn to VLC media player 1.1.4, everything just works well!

So sometimes it depends on the media server. You can try RTSP from YouTube (go to m.youtube.com and then right click on some video -> copy location link -> that is the RTSP link you need).

Comment: I found the solution. Transmission should be within preffered setting by Android. for more details, plz check @ http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Comment: The native RTSP stack may not be sending GET_PARAMETER to keep the connection alive... check out http://net7mma.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

I searched and tried a lot of codes to play RTSP on Android And finally, I found this library.
Hope this helps for whom looking for this kind of
[RTSP Player using Vlc](https://github.com/pedroSG94/vlc-example-streamplayer)

Answer (score 0):

I was reading and researching about this subject for about a whole month and I used the *VLC library* to play *RTSP* streams from the camera although it works fine the problem with this library was the latency it had. I needed a library to play the stream in real-time so we were testing *Gstreamer* on Linux and Nvidia board it works fine with no latency and I managed to rebuild the *Gstreamer* library on my application and it works fine and it is so powerful. [The Gstreamer Library](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/android/index.html?gi-language=c)