# How to display live streaming (http video) in android

Tags: android, http, video-streaming, live-streaming

I am trying to display following http video in android. But things are not working. If the http video is a video file then it works perfectly. But if it is live streaming then it can not display or plan?

Can anyone help me in this problem? Thanks in advance :-)

Live http video link:
http://trackfield.webcam.oregonstate.edu/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android and MJPEG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205191/android-and-mjpeg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's about RTSP live streaming...

**may this will help you** [RTSP live streaming in android...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274906/play-rtsp-streaming-in-an-android-application)

Comment: It's MJPEG over HTTP... this has nothing to do with RTSP.

Comment: Anybody has any idea about this question? I really appreciate any solution regarding this problem.