# How to achive better quality with libav on android surface?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, libav, android-ffmpeg

Playing video from RTSP stream on Android surface using solution from this repo
https://github.com/alexandruc/android-ffmpeg-player/blob/master/android-ffmpeg-player/jni/ffmpeg-player.c

Video is playng but have a lot of glitches especially when something moving.
Have not enought expirience using **libav**.
Will be happy if someone can help or give links on some tutorials or community.

Here is the function to display video on surface.

```
void* decodeAndRender(void *voidArgs) {
auto *args = (decode_args*)voidArgs;
CamCon* cc = getCamCon(args->name);

ANativeWindow_Buffer    windowBuffer;
AVPacket                packet;
int                     i=0;
int                     frameFinished;
int                     lineCnt;

int counter = 0;
while(av_read_frame(cc->formatCtx, &packet)>=0 && cc->isConnect) {
    counter = 1;
    // Is this a packet from the video stream?
    if(packet.stream_index==cc->videoStreamIdx) {
        // Decode video frame
        avcodec_decode_video2(cc->codecCtx, cc->decodedFrame, &frameFinished, &packet);
        // Did we get a video frame?
        if(frameFinished) {
            // RECORD video
            if(cc->isRecord)
                recordMP4(packet, cc);

            // DISPLAY video
            // Convert the image from its native format to RGBA
            sws_scale (
                    cc->sws_ctx,
                    (uint8_t const * const *)cc->decodedFrame->data,
                    cc->decodedFrame->linesize,
                    0,
                    cc->codecCtx->height,
                    cc->frameRGBA->data,
                    cc->frameRGBA->linesize
            );
            // lock the window buffer
            if (ANativeWindow_lock(cc->window, &windowBuffer, NULL) < 0) {
                LOGE("cannot lock window");
            } else {
                // draw the frame on buffer
                LOGI("copy buffer %d:%d:%d", cc->displayWidth, cc->displayHeight, cc->displayWidth * cc->displayHeight*4);
                LOGI("window buffer: %d:%d:%d", windowBuffer.width,
                     windowBuffer.height, windowBuffer.stride);
                memcpy(windowBuffer.bits, cc->buffer,  cc->displayWidth * cc->displayHeight * 4);
                // unlock the window buffer and post it to display
                ANativeWindow_unlockAndPost(cc->window);
                // count number of frames
                ++i;
            }
        }
    }
    // Free the packet that was allocated by av_read_frame
    av_free_packet(&packet);
}
LOGI("total No. of frames decoded and rendered %d", i);
finish(args->env, args->name);
```

}

Comment: You sohould probably read the answers to *[Play RTSP streaming in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274906/play-rtsp-streaming-in-an-android-application)*

Comment: @AlexCohn, thx for your response. I seen this answer already. But I have no problems play RTSP stream on Android. I have several different implementations and my problem in playing with ffmpeg(libav libraries). I'm need full control of the video stream (record/share/play video at the same time with minimum resourse usage). 
Or I have problem with codec formats in my code? If so can you explain what actually should I change.