# Can not play video from RTSP URL

Tags: android, rtsp

i have used the rtsp://***** url streaming from wowza server but can't able to play video from it. I have tried all with videoview , libvlc library.

Vlc give this error: 
`Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL`

and videoview gives
 `E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
 E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)`

I have also add the permission of internet in manifest file.

Help me with this, how I can play video from given URL.

Thanks.

Comment: Your stream might not be of a format supported by Android.

Comment: i check in wowza test player it worked fine there , also worked previously with vitameo library , but i can't use at these time because it have some issues with android version

Comment: Yeah that's my meant that _rtsp_ stream might not be supported by Android. You should dig a google regarding _RTPS Android Support_

Comment: I have tried all the possible solution

Comment: Have you checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274906/play-rtsp-streaming-in-an-android-application), [this](https://www.truiton.com/2015/03/stream-rtmp-live-android/) and [this](https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5333)??

Comment: Can you get a packet dump from VLC with Wireshark, currently it is not certain if this a network, protocol, or video level issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use Exo Player to play RTSP. Exo Player has a feature to play live stream videos/audios.

Comment: @SaloniShah Have you checked above links which i shared?

Answer (score 0):

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/android/video.html
bit of work to setup but just download a tutorial and modify it. Definitely supports RTSP.